# Angular Material tab ripple effect on click does not apply to full tab after stretch

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-tab

**UPDATE:**

This issue is considered an 'edge case' and will not be fixed by the Angular team. You can take a look at this github issue for the full detail: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/23051.

I still like to get a workaround. I have tried to disable the ripple effect on the tab group and trigger it on tab-change but I have some problems triggering it on the individual tab. Any direction would be appreciated.

**Original Descirption:**

I'm using Angular 11 with Angular Material. I have a simple tab group with a "mat-stretch-tabs" directive in order to have the tabs expand to the correct width depending on the content. However, if you click on the tab where the content width is larger than the previous tab content, the ripple effect doesn't get applied to the full tab-width but only to the initial tab-width, as illustrated in the below screenshot:

[image: ripple effect not full tab]

I have created a stackblitz to illustrate it:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular11-mat-stretch-tabs-ripple-not-apply-to-full-tab?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Just click between the tabs (label 1 and label 2) and look at the ripple effect on the second tab.

Am I missing something or is there a simple fix to this?

**Edit:**
From what I understand, the 'stretch-tabs' directive can be used at this specific use case where I want the tab to grow to match the content size, but it doesn't work well with its default ripple effect (Feel free to point out my misunderstanding). I do not want to have a fixed width for the parent card (that contains the tab group) because it fixes the width for the tabs. Instead, the tab width should change depending on the content it contains. I want to know if there is a way to fix this.

Comment: It is because of variable width. Fix the card width.

Comment: @Vishnudev I know I can set the width for the whole card (containing the tab group) but I want it to be responsive to the content, so the tab width would have to vary. Isn't it the whole point of mat-stretch-tabs?

Comment: Making it responsive won't be an issue. Example set `%` width using `bootstrap` columns or manually. `mat-stretch-tabs` is for `100%` width of the parent. But, when animation triggers before the width set because of content, it causes this problem.

Comment: @Vishnudev Sorry I am not exactly sure what you mean. If I set the width for the parent card, the tab would start with that width and never change. I do have the width of the child card of the tab set to 100%.